# Events in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are the controller actions an analogous feature to the ASP.NET events?
and How to Handle postback in Asp.Net MVC as there is no viewstate and postbacks in MVC what is the alternative for that in the framework?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not analogous.

Think about it as uber public method (accessible through http get/post/etc.) that returns html.

There aren't such a thing as postback anymore. Neither is viewstate.

Basically - you receive input and form output. That's it.

With correct way of doing that - you don't even need an alternative.